# Popup not opening after icon click in unpacked extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am following the tutorial here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Everything works apart from the pop-up when you click the icon.

I have tried downloading the finished code and also changing `page_action` to `browser_action`.

Is there some issue seeing the popup page when loading unpacked?

Comment: The tutorial is known to be buggy, https://crbug.com/839545. Looks like the linked zip is not yet fixed unlike the code in the documentation itself. Anyway, it's better to start with these [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: Error liked has been fixed, no errors are showing, just the popup not appearing.  Thanks for link, I will investigate them

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome://extensions in your browser and then click on the Errors button lying on your unpacked extension, this will open a window which will display all the errors/ issues encountered while loading your extension.